# gain access to file in list

Tags: python, file-io, python-3.x

My search-and-destroy type program has ended up in vain. I have successfully made up the list but the program terminates at `PermissionError`.
My code goes as follows:

```
import os
count=0
while(count<4):
    file_list=[]
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(os.path.expandvars('%windir%')):
        for f_name in files:
            if f_name=='infected-file-1':
                file_list.append(root+"\\"+f_name)
                str1='\n'.join(file_list)
                for x in str1.split('\n'): pass
                os.remove(x)
                continue
            for root, dirs, files in os.walk(os.path.expandvars('%windir%')):
                for f_name in files:
                    if f_name=='infected-file-2':
                        file_list.append(root+"\\"+f_name)
                        str1='\n'.join(file_list)
                        for z in str1.split('\n'): pass
                        os.remove(z)
```

The program does start well but isn't able to delete the file as there is a permission error

So I was planning to use os.system to use takeown to gain full control but how do i use this in syntax i.e. `os.system("takeown /f x")` where 'x'=python variable

You may suggest me to use the print the `file_list` to get the address of the file and then use takeown but that is not what I want. [I don't my program to include user interaction]

The while command is being used to repeat the process to ensure files do not exist anymore!

Comment: I don't understand why you `append`, then `join`, then loop over the `split` but do nothing with the loop variable.  It looks like the only point is to set `z` to the last entry of `file_list`, but `z = file_list[-1]` should do the same.  What am I missing?

Comment: @DSM: actually the append is used to print the file to be deleted; join is used as I encountered an error earlier which I can't remember right now.
I am a beginner in Python so I am afraid to edit that code over there.
But you do give me a point. I'll look into it THANKS :)

Answer (score 2):

You should really use the [`subprocess` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) instead of `os.system`:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.call(['takeown', '/f', x])
```

The first argument of the [`.call()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call) is a list of command arguments, including the command itself. Just use the variable `x` as an element of that list.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution :P All it took was some peace-of-mind ;)

I just placed this code `os.system("cmd /c takeown /f "+x)` to gain access to the file and then the deletion succeeded.

As a newbie, this is an achievement

THANK YOU STACKOVERFLOW

Comment: I don't know much about Windows, but will that handle special characters correctly?

Comment: While this solution seems like it works, I would highly suggest you take the advice given by @MartijnPieters -- It's a much more flexible approach in the long run and it pays to learn good habits early :)